# How do you check that a jagged array is not multidimensional in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a matrix which is a jagged array. The matrix comes in different sizes, like the following:

```
char[][] grid1 = {
    new char[] { '1', '1', '0', '1', '0' },
    new char[] { '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' },
    new char[] { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' }
};

char[][] grid2 = {
    new char[] { '1' }
};
```

The problem I have is that I need to loop over the matrix to get or set its elements. I do this using a nested for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[1].Length; j++)
    {
        System.Console.Write(grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

The above loop works fine on grid1 because it's multidimensional. But I get an error for grid2 because it only has one dimension. The error occurs when I use "grid[1].Length". I tried "GetLength(1)" but I get the same problem because the second dimension doesn't exist.

How do I check that the matrix is multi-dimensional to avoid an exception thrown? Also is their a way to loop a jagged array regardless of how many dimensions it has?

Comment: use grid[i].Lenght instead of grid[1].Lenght

Comment: also, it isn't about dimensions, what if 3rd row has 4 items instead of 5? exception again. you're trying to always access 2nd row of your array to get count number, which is wrong anyway

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk Thanks for pointing that out, I can see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk make it an answer so this can be accepted :)

Comment: Also, C# is strongly typed, so I think compiler does all the checking for you (if you try to insert some value instead of array, when array is expected, you get compile time error).

Comment: I think you are confusing "dimension" and "length". `grid2` still has 2 dimensions. It's just that it has a length of 1 in each of the dimensions.

Comment: @Sweeper really? `grid2` has 2 dimensions and both of which have length of 1?? I'm definitely confused. I'm going to revise this topic again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jagged array is always multidimensional by declaration. char[][] means you have array of arrays of chars. You can't pass char instead of char[] into char[0] element of array, it will lead to compile-time error. So we never check, if it is multidimensional, compiler makes it instead of us.

Your actual problem is using 2nd row to get Length of any row you want to access. You always need to get Lenght of row you want to access.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].Length; j++)
    {
        System.Console.Write(grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Worst case you can deal with, when work with jagged array, is missing initialization. For example,

```
char[][] grid = new int[3][];
```

You have an array of following declaration. After this declaration you always have 3 rows, but still do not have any data in them. It is array of 3 nulls. So the previous code will not work. If you're not sure if your jagged have all your rows initialized, then you should check if it is not null.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
{
    if (grid[i] != null)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].Length; j++)
        {
            System.Console.Write(grid[i][j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: don't  think this actually solves your problem, but the guy in the comments seem right, use `grid[0]`.

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
{
    // Check if the current value is an array, if not display the value instead.
    if(grid[i] != typeof (char[])
    {
        System.Console.Write(grid[i]);
        continue;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < grid[1].Length; j++)
    {
        System.Console.Write(grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: @sommen thanks for the effort, I might actually need your answer. I'll get back to it after I do some changes.

Comment: Glad to be of help and thanks for the upvote, ill leave this here then.

Comment: The problem and the actual question differ. Simply change your code to work on any jagged array. If you access grid[i], then you always want grid[i].Lenght to see, how many items contains row. grid[0] solve the problem with array of 1 row, but it would not work, if 2nd row has less items than 1st.

Comment: @sommen I did the changes and in fact I won't need your answer. But I really appreciate it. You taught me something new but the answer addressed my problem. Thanks you again.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk you do answer the second part of my question which is How do I loop regardless of the number of dimensions. So if you put an answer, I will pick it.

Comment: @Sea_Ocean your first doen't work either. you cannot compare grid[i] and typeof(char[]). at least you should use grid[i].GetType() to get a compilable code. Also it is always true, if you have char[][] declaration of the array.

Comment: @DzianisKarpuk I changed all my code to grid[i] as you pointed out and now everything works. So I don't need to check whether a jagged array is multidimensional or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the jagged array forms a matrix (i.e. every subarray has the same length), you could do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
{
    // we can be sure that grid[0] always exist it ever goes into the outer loop
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].Length; j++)
    {
        System.Console.Write(grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

But if so, you could just use a 2D array `char[,]`, instead of a jagged array!

```
char[,] grid1 = {
    { '1', '1', '0', '1', '0' },
    { '1', '1', '0', '0', '0' },
    { '0', '0', '0', '0', '0' }
};

for (int i = 0 ; i < grid1.GetUpperBound(0) ; i++) {
    for (int j = 0 ; j < grid1.GetUpperBound(1) ; i++) {
        System.Console.Write(grid[i, j]);
    }
}
```

If each sub array can have different lengths, you can use `grid[i]` to access each of their lengths:

```
for (int i = 0; i < grid.Length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < grid[i].Length; j++)
    {
        System.Console.Write(grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: A jagged array is what I was given so I can't change it to a normal multidimensional array. I wish that was the case because I'm more familiar with it but I guess I learned something new. thanks for the answer. I'll pick it because it answers all my questions.